# How to detect the view on map, based on address we have filled in the address field based on click of view on map using angular8

Tags: angular, google-maps

i searched for fetching the view on google map based on the address i enter in input field, but no where i can find my exact match, can anyone suggest me how can this be implemented without using any plugins but by using only the google documentation.

Here is my demo:

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbbvci?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Here if the type the address and click on enter, it must show me like this,

https://www.google.com/maps/place/7205+Vidalia+Rd,+Pass+Christian,+MS+39571,+USA/@30.3883765,-89.2804678,16.54z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x889c30f88496c417:0x3f64091c737e755b!8m2!3d30.3881083!4d-89.2781026

html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Mailing Address1 <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> View on Map</a>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mailing Address1">
              </div>
```

I have given address as:

```
mailing address 1: 7205 Vidalia Rd
city: Pass Christian
state:Mississippi
zip:39571
```

fetching latitude and longitude:

```
this.geoAddress = "HoneyWell+null+Company+null+null+560076+null+null"
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': this.geoAddress}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did few changes to your code.

> **Step 1:** to use GoogleMaps api you need to have a maps KEY (Create API key credentials)

- Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
- From Side Menu go to APIs & Services -> Crdentials -> Create Credentials -> API Key (Copy the key)

Use this key in your code

```
s.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={ PASTE_KEY_HERE }&libraries=places&callback=initMap";
```

> **Step 2:** We have to enable few APIs

- Go to `API Manager`
- Click on `Overview`
- Search for below APIs and Click on **Enable** button

  - **Geocoding API**
  - **Geolocation API**
  - **Maps JavaScript API**
  - **Places API**

Here is the working [Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6utzm)

Here is the [Github](https://github.com/AkhilNaidu09/angular-google-maps-javascript) repo, if you have any issues post here in github.

[image: Image attachment]

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: thanks for response, but on click of view map, it is not showing me location, i agree it is asking for billing but it can show the location know?

Comment: As I already reached maximum number of hits for today it was asking for billing, don't open in new window, try it in development mode it will work. Its working for me in development mode (don't click on **Open in new window Live** ) or else you can create new key and enable the APIs mentioned above.

Comment: updated my post with an Image attachment. Currently pointer was not showing and  I am working on it. But navigation to the entered address was happening.

Comment: yes i saw, that pointer comes and goes off, it is working as i expected

Comment: but if i comment the latitude and longitude manual values, then it is not taking.Also i was trying with other approach, here based on address value given trying to fetch the latitude and longitude

Comment: Latitude and longitude values are just for initial loading of map. As you see I have given Sydney latitude and longitude values you can give any location value.. then I am passing new address details as a text and I am searching for that address using maps service this will return new latitude and longitude and binds to the map

Comment: i have posted what i have tried for lat and long finding, jus have a look

Comment: Hi akhil, any idea about finding lat and longitude, i tried in many ways but couldnt find

Comment: I will have a try and let you know

Comment: ok thanks,even i will be trying, incase if i am able to find i will let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205728/discussion-between-akhil-naidu-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: Hi @akhil, i am getting result as null and status is Zero_Results

Comment: i need your help