# How to change the value of the url without refreshing the page in angular8

Tags: angular, angular-router

i have used window.open to open the page in the new tab, and in the new tab,from the main screen i have an option for edit and view, so if i click on view in url i am passing 1, and on click of edit i am passing 2, so totally 3 values i am passing, with 2 codes. 
Now, when i click on view button from main page, i get url like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/data?dt=1211-1211-1
```

So, in the view i have a Edit button, which enables all the field for editing, so here i want my url to be

```
http://localhost:4200/data?dt=1211-1211-2,
```

So, that it will be in the edit mode.
I have used activated router to get the values from the url from main page to new tab

```
 let url = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.dt.split("-");
    this.gp= url[0];
    this.ap = url[1];
    this.mode = url[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to the current route with new query params, which will not reload your page, but will update query params

```
editMode(){
const queryParams = this.gp.toString() + this.ap.toString() + '2';    
this.router.navigate(
        [], 
        {
          relativeTo: this.route,
          queryParams: queryParams,
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
}
```

Comment: yes but, i want to retain everything like that only and change only the mode to 2, so i need 1211-1211-2, that is how?

Comment: Enjoy Happy Coding 

Comment: any idea about how this could be done?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642589/how-to-detect-the-view-on-map-based-on-address-we-have-filled-in-the-address-fi

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I posted answer for this issue please have a look at if it worked please give and upvote :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642589/how-to-detect-the-view-on-map-based-on-address-we-have-filled-in-the-address-fi#answer-59663933